# R implementation of a Multinominal Problem: Probability of n-times head in k throws with varying probabilities per throw

Tags: r, statistics, probability, coin-flipping

im struggleing with a potential easy to solve Problem. I have a dataset with 100k series of coin throws with varying k (throws). For each series I want to compute the the probability for each discrete n-state of getting head (sic!). E.g. 4 throws with the probabilities of c(.25,.5,.25,.75) to throw head. No I would like to calculate of how probable it is to get 0,1,2,3,4 -times head.  I assume it is a different variant of a classical multinominal distribution. Is there a easy R command that I could apply or a formula ?

Greetings and Thanks!
David

So far I just tried to create a function that hard calcualtes each case, like 3 throws with

prob = c(0.3,0.2,.5)

#only 1
no_sites = (1-.3)*(1-.2)*(1-.5)

#3
one_site = ((.3)*(1-.2)*(1-.5)) + ((1-.3)*(.2)*(1-.5)) + ((1-.3)*(1-.2)*(.5))

#3
two_sites = ((.3)*(.2)*(1-.5)) + ((1-.3)*(.2)*(.5)) + ((.3)*(1-.2)*(.5))

#1
three_sites = (.3)*(.2)*(.5)

sum(no_sites, one_site, two_sites, three_sites) = 1

Yet there should be a formula that is able to do so, without annoying hardcoded caclulations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum of Bernouilli distributions is a [Poisson Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution). There's the package `poisbinom` that you can use to calculate those probabilities.

With the vector of probabilities you gave:

```
install.packages("poisbinom")

library(poisbinom)

pp <- c(.25,.5,.25,.75)
dpoisbinom(4, pp)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Apparently, I misclassified the problem!